# Serving up json file from nginx

Tags: nginx

I am trying to serve a file through nginx. nginx is trying to open the file at the wrong path and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my nginx.conf file

```
worker_processes  1;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    include servers/*.conf;
}
```

Inside of servers, I have example.conf

```
server {
    listen *:80;
    server_name localhost;

    location /hello.json {
        alias /tmp/hello.json;
    }
}
```

The file does exist at `/tmp/hello.json`. The error reported by nginx is

> 2020/02/18 10:42:40 [error] 269#0: *9 open() "/usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.17.7/html/hello.json" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /hello.json HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"

when I try to access this file in my browser at `localhost/hello.json`. It seems to me that nginx is ignoring the alias directive. How can I fix this?

Yes, I restarted nginx after each modification. Yes, ALL files exist on the hard drive.

Comment: Is your `example.conf` located to `/etc/nginx/servers/` ? did you reload nginx after adding your new config ?
 -- 
change `listen *:80;` by `listen 80;` -- change `server_name localhost;` with `server_name _;`

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to test the configuration and view exactly which files Nginx is reading.